# How can I show framebuffer drawing on surfaceview?

Tags: android, surfaceview, framebuffer

I have done some drawings on framebuffer, but they just do not show up on my surfaceview?

JNI code:

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_com_example_testskia_Skia_initFramebuffer(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    const char *devfile = "/dev/graphics/fb0";
    int fbFd = 0;

    int location = 0;
    int bytes_per_pixel;

    // Open the file for reading and writing
    fbFd = open (devfile, O_RDWR);
    if (fbFd == -1) {
        perror("Error cannot open framebuffer device");
        LOGI("Error cannot open framebuffer device");
        exit (1);
    }
    LOGI("Succeed open framebuffer device");

    //获取finfo信息并显示
    if (ioctl (fbFd, FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO, &finfo) == -1) {
        perror("Error reading fixed information");
        LOGI("Error reading fixed information");
        exit (2);
    }
    LOGI("Succeed reading fixed information");

    //获取vinfo信息并显示
    if (ioctl (fbFd, FBIOGET_VSCREENINFO, &vinfo) == -1) {
        perror("Error reading variable information");
        LOGI("Error reading variable information");
        exit (3);
    }
    LOGI("Succeed reading variable information");

    bytes_per_pixel = vinfo.bits_per_pixel / 8;
    screensize = vinfo.xres * vinfo.yres * bytes_per_pixel;   //单帧画面空间  单位：字节
    LOGI("vinfo.xres=%d  vinfo.yres=%d  bytes_per_pixel=%d", vinfo.xres, vinfo.yres, bytes_per_pixel);
    LOGI("screensize=%ld\n", screensize);

    // Figure out the size of the screen in bytes
    //screensize = finfo.smem_len;
    //LOGI("Succeed screensize:%ld", screensize);

    // Map the device to memory
    frameBuffer = (char *) mmap(0, screensize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fbFd, 0);
    if (frameBuffer == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("Error Failed to map framebuffer device to memory");
        LOGI("Error Failed to map framebuffer device to memory");
        exit (4);
    }
    LOGI("Succeed map framebuffer device to memory");

    memset(frameBuffer, 0, screensize);

    performSpeedTest(frameBuffer, screensize);

    for(int i = 0; i < (854*480); i++)
        frameBuffer[i] = 0x00ff0000;

    sleep(5);


    /*char *buffer = (char*)malloc(vinfo.yres * finfo.line_length);
    for (int i = 0; i <= 0xff; i += 0x0f) {
        memset(buffer, i, vinfo.yres * finfo.line_length);
        flush_screen(buffer, frameBuffer, vinfo.xres, vinfo.yres);
        //sleep(1);
    }*/

    //draw rectangle
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    int guage_height = 20, step = 10;
    y = (vinfo.yres - guage_height) / 2 - 2;       // Where we are going to put the pixel
    for (x = step - 2; x < vinfo.xres - step + 2; x++) {
        location = (x+vinfo.xoffset) * (vinfo.bits_per_pixel/8) +
                       (y+vinfo.yoffset) * finfo.line_length;
        *((unsigned short int*)(frameBuffer + location)) = 255;
    }
    y = (vinfo.yres + guage_height) / 2 + 2;       // Where we are going to put the pixel
    for (x = step - 2; x < vinfo.xres - step + 2; x++) {
        location = (x+vinfo.xoffset) * (vinfo.bits_per_pixel/8) +
                       (y+vinfo.yoffset) * finfo.line_length;
        *((unsigned short int*)(frameBuffer + location)) = 255;
    }
    x = step - 2;
    for (y = (vinfo.yres - guage_height) / 2 - 2; y < (vinfo.yres + guage_height) / 2 + 2; y++) {
        location = (x+vinfo.xoffset) * (vinfo.bits_per_pixel/8) +
                       (y+vinfo.yoffset) * finfo.line_length;
        *((unsigned short int*)(frameBuffer + location)) = 255;
    }
    x = vinfo.xres - step + 2;
    for (y = (vinfo.yres - guage_height) / 2 - 2; y < (vinfo.yres + guage_height) / 2 + 2; y++) {
        location = (x+vinfo.xoffset) * (vinfo.bits_per_pixel/8) +
                       (y+vinfo.yoffset) * finfo.line_length;
        *((unsigned short int*)(frameBuffer + location)) = 255;
    }
    // Figure out where in memory to put the pixel
    for ( x = step; x < vinfo.xres - step; x++ ) {
        for ( y = (vinfo.yres - guage_height) / 2; y < (vinfo.yres + guage_height) / 2; y++ ) {
            location = (x+vinfo.xoffset) * (vinfo.bits_per_pixel/8) +
                       (y+vinfo.yoffset) * finfo.line_length;
            if ( vinfo.bits_per_pixel == 32 ) {
                *(frameBuffer + location) = 100;        // Some blue
                *(frameBuffer + location + 1) = 15+(x-100)/2;     // A little green
                *(frameBuffer + location + 2) = 200-(y-100)/5;    // A lot of red
                *(frameBuffer + location + 3) = 0;      // No transparency
            } else { //assume 16bpp
                unsigned char b = 255 * x / (vinfo.xres - step);
                unsigned char g = 255;     // (x - 100)/6 A little green
                unsigned char r = 255;    // A lot of red
                unsigned short int t = make16color(r, g, b);
                *((unsigned short int*)(frameBuffer + location)) = t;
            }
        }
        //printf("x = %d, temp = %d\n", x, temp);
        //sleep to see it
        usleep(200);
    }

}

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_com_example_testskia_Skia_initSkia(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jobject _bitmap) {
    LOGI("Java_com_example_testskia_Skia_initSkia");

    //register_android_graphics_Graphics(env, clazz, _bitmap);

    AndroidBitmapInfo  info;
    int ret;

    ret = AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, _bitmap, &info);
    LOGI("Java_com_example_testskia_Skia_initSkia info");

    ret = AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, _bitmap, (void**)&pixels);
    LOGI("Java_com_example_testskia_Skia_initSkia pixels");

    int width = (int)info.width;
    int height = (int)info.height;
    LOGI("Java_com_example_testskia_Skia_initSkia end width = %d, height=%d", width, height);

    sk_bitmap = SkBitmap();
    sk_bitmap.setConfig(SkBitmap::kARGB_8888_Config, width, height, 0);
    sk_bitmap.setPixels((void*)pixels);
    sk_canvas = new SkCanvas(sk_bitmap);

    paint.setStyle(SkPaint::kStroke_Style);
    paint.setColor(SK_ColorGREEN);

    sk_canvas->drawLine(220, 300, 400, 300, paint);
    memcpy(frameBuffer, sk_bitmap.getPixels(), screensize);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your setup environment settings?